# function call error: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

I've seen other topics with the same subject matter/issue, but none of those solutions apply to me.

I'm receiving the error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

When trying to execute shoot=play(fk,int(uCard),int(b)) in the following code.  I'm trying to call function 'play' while passing 3 values (a boolean and 2 int) and want a string value returned:

```
    field=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0]]

    def play(fk1,uCard1,b1):
        shoot1=''
        a=0
        while a<(len(field)-1):
           if field[a][b1]<uCard1:
              print('you beat player '+str(field[a][b1]))
              field[a][b1]=0
              shoot1='True'
          else:
            if fk1==False:
                uCard=0
                print('player '+str(field[a][b1])+' beat you. attack ends.')
                field[a][b1]=0
                shoot1='False'
                break
            else:
                print('Your FK beats player '+str(field[a][b1]))
                fk1=False
                field[a][b1]=0
               shoot1='True'
            a=a+1
        return shoot1

    #MAIN BEGINS HERE
    fk=False
    shoot='False'
    b=1

    uCard=random.randint(1, 10)

    if uCard==1:
           print('FOUL!... you drew an indirect free kick...')
           fk=True
           uCard=random.randint(1, 10)
           shoot=play(fk,int(uCard),int(b))
    else:
           shoot=play(fk,int(uCard),int(b))
```

Comment: You've overwritten the built-in `str` with something else. Make sure you don't have `str=` anywhere in your code.

Comment: str= is nowhere in my code

Comment: What about `play=`? (reassigning `str` will only cause that error if you're calling `str`; you are calling `play`)

Comment: $#!T... I did have play= in another part of my code.  That's what was causing the issue... I had a function named 'play' and a variable named 'play'.  Once I changed my function name to 'play1' the error went away.  Thanks pycoder!